# Why aren't there traditional namespaces in TypeScript? How do I group classes without them?

Tags: namespace, typescript

"Traditional" namespaces in the sense that Java, C#, and PHP use it. Spaces to organize related classes and sub-namespaces that span across multiple files.

How do I rewire my brain to think without namespaces for organizing related classes together?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12737942.  In short, use modules, or use `namespace` in Typescript 1.5 or later.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Namespaces in TypeScript aren't traditional namespace that supports one file for one class practise like other languages.

Comment: How are they not like "traditional" namespaces?   The semantics are the same from my experience.

Comment: @DavidD: Please see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/298308/why-arent-there-traditional-namespaces-in-typescript-how-do-i-group-classes-wi?noredirect=1#comment619371_298308

Comment: but C# doesn't force you to only have one class per namespace per file either.  If I want 5 different classes in one file, I can do that.  I fail to see the distinction where TypeScript namespaces are different in any meaningful way.

Comment: @DavidD: C# doesn't "force" you to do that.

But TypeScript does force me to write all classes in one file, if I want them to be in same namespace.

Comment: I just created a gist with 3 files, two that are in the same namespace, and one that is in a parent namespace to those two, and works just fine cross files.  There is no requirement to have all your classes in one file.   https://gist.github.com/david-driscoll/fc95b5331cc4dfff6388

Comment: @DavidD: Can you modify your gist to use an "index.js" – that can be executed using NodeJS – to boot your app, instead of a "index.html"? That's where we run into trouble.

Comment: Node is a different scenario, and you almost always use what TypeScript calls external modules, using some sort of module loader.  In the case of Node, that is commonjs (and that is what the tsconfig.json should reference).  In that case, you are correct your namespaces won't auto populate, but that isn't a failure of TypeScript so much as how Node itself works (each script is sandboxed from each other).  You have two choices.  1) Don't use namespaces, and just use external modules, like other node apps. 2) Compile your TypeScript into a single file, index.js.

Comment: @DavidD Well, I guess I'd have to keep away from NodeJS until such ability is created that would allow me to put classes of one namespace in different files.

Comment: You'll never get that with nodejs, because of how the files are sandboxed.  You just have to look at your classes as distinct dependencies instead of having common namespaces.  It is a different way to look at things, but you do get used to it fairly quickly.

Comment: dunno anything about nodejs, but you can definitely have one class per file exactly like c#. use web essentials. typescript compiles to .js, web essentials packages many .js into a single .js file, and even minifies it, and all your files (for one "library") end up in a single minified .js file. (oh, this discussion is older than I realized, sorry.)